# "On Error Goto 0" before Exit Function

Tags: vb6, error-handling

The default error handler template in MzTools is:

```
On Error GoTo {PROCEDURE_NAME}_Error

    {PROCEDURE_BODY}

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit {PROCEDURE_TYPE}

{PROCEDURE_NAME}_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure {PROCEDURE_NAME} of {MODULE_TYPE} {MODULE_NAME}"
```

Note that `On Error Goto 0` is placed directly prior to the Exit statement.  What is the point of doing this?  It seems redundant.  The error handler for the function will turn off anyway when the function exits.

Answer (score 3):

`on error goto 0` turns *off* error handling in the current scope and reverts to the default case.

In this instance, the procedure wants an error handler to be active for the duration of the function but it wants it turned off upon exit. As you say, it's not necessary in this case since the scope of the error handler is the `{PROCEDURE_TYPE}` so it will be reverted on exit.

But sometimes, coders (especially those that generate templates) like to clean up after themselves even when not technically necessary, such as freeing allocated memory in a C program before exiting.

That's what I suspect is the case here, that it really *is* just supposition.

Comment: As I said in my question, the error handler for the procedure will turn off anyway when the procedure exits. What would be the point of having an `On Error Goto 0` right before the Exit Function?

Comment: I'd say the author of MzTools just screwed up. Does make you wonder what else in there is wrong too.  Probably nothing fatal though, it's a pretty well-tested product.

Comment: No. its about clearing the Err object, not turning off the error handler. See wqw's answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about turning off current error handler but about clearing `Err` object.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    pvTest
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub pvTest()
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print 1 / 0
'    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Then remove commented line.

Comment: +1 Exactly. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242692(v=vs.60).aspx) Exit Sub / Exit Function will also clear the Err object. Simply falling through to End Sub will not. The default MZTools error handler does include Exit Sub / Exit Function. But no harm being explicit.

Comment: @MarkJ: Adding `Exit Sub` to the sample above does not clear `Err` object. `Err.Clear` does :-))

Comment: Exit Sub (and the other cases) only clear the error object if they're done in the error handling routine itself.

Comment: I had a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510158/why-is-it-wrong-to-exit-a-sub-from-inside-of-a-error-handler-block.

So from the above comments and answers i gather that the issue is with regard to the Err object. So what is the consensus? 

Using Exit Sub will not clear the Err object? Is that the only reason why we should not use it like that?

Comment: I use `On Error GoTo 0` only when suppressing errors with `On Error Resume Next` in short routines (these are rare one-liners like `SearchCollection`, type-casting, etc.). I also use it just before raising custom errors with `Err.Raise ...` so these don't get logged in our custom error handler.