# Why is it wrong to exit a sub from inside of a error handler block?

Tags: vb6, error-handling

I read somewhere that exiting out of an error handling block is not recommended. Sadly they did not give an explanation why?

I was curious why is it so. I did find something related to this in the discussion at ["On Error Goto 0" before Exit Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395149/on-error-goto-0-before-exit-function) but not sure if that is the definitive answer. They talk about the Err object not being cleared. Is that the only issue and if so is there a work around?

Is this wrong? If it is, then what is the recommended way of exiting the function? I am not a huge supporter of go to statements, they make the code harder to follow.

```vb
    Private Sub Foo2()
        On Error Resume Next
            'Multiple lines of code

            If Not Foo(arg1,arg2) Then
                Exit Sub  'Can I exit here?
            End If

            'Multiple lines of code
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Goto` is absolutely fine if used with discipline. It is the equivalent of a `Try ... Catch` block in more modern languages. Definitely better than `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is pure evil when applied to more than one line of code that may raise an exception that you cannot otherwise prevent.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the better way would be is to do something like:

```
Private Sub Foo2()
    On Error Goto ErrHandler
        'Multiple lines of code

        If Not Foo(arg1,arg2) Then
            Exit Sub  'Can I exit here?
        End If

        Multiple lines of code

ErrHandler:
    Error handling mechanism here.
End Sub
```

Comment: No my question is regarding the Exit Sub in the if statement. Is it ok to exit a sub from inside an on error block?

Comment: On Error Resume Next is a tricky devil, what it does is it allows the execution of the next line of codes even after an error has occured, thus at most times it will have unexpected results. Like on my post its better to use a error handling mechanism rather than using on error resume next, unless you are 100% sure that resuming after an error will not have an effect on the sequential logic of your code.

Comment: @MAC for sure you can exit the sub inside an on error block, the on error statement in VB6 is just a label to tell where the system goes if an error occurs but nothing else, so it won't be a problem if you exit it within an on error block

Comment: @Nick From what i gather from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395149/on-error-goto-0-before-exit-function it may have an effect on the Err object. 

Personally I don't think it should be a problem, but i was reading recommendations in some training presentation and they said that we should avoid it. So i was wondering if i was missing something and if someone knew why they would recommend something like that.

Comment: @MAC I am not sure why. I was told not doing this because of a bad design pattern. I guess there may be a better reason for this

Comment: @Nick I agree with the resume next. That is probably not the safest way of doing things. I am more interested about having an exit sub from inside of an error block.

Comment: @MAC can you post an example of the code? So we can see what your colleagues considered bad?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the warnings about `On Error Resume Next` (heed them!!) there are no problems with this code. The scope of the error handling statement is the Foo2 Sub, it will expire when you Exit it. The dangers arise when you call another Sub within the For block, which in itself may call other Subs. *Those* subs will inherit the On Error Resume Next and will give you nightmares for years on end when Errors raised from them are swallowed...

Answer (score 0):

In my past experience with VB6, using Resume Next wasn't a good idea.  I never used it.  My code did its best to avoid errors at all, and in the case where one happened, it would always go down to an error handler block.  The question you linked to illustrates the use of MZTools, which I used liberally.

So, my point is that the Resume Next code is most likely just an exercise, but not real production code.  If that is true, then you wouldn't have to clear the Err object before Exit Sub, because the Err object wouldn't have anything in it anyway.  If you DID encounter an error, it would Goto the ErrorHandler label and continue from there.  I that handler, yes, you would ideally want to do something with the Err object, then return appropriately to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange your code line this and ensure that the exit sub or exit function always comes just before the ErrorHandler:

```
Private Sub Foo2()
   On Error Goto ErrHandler

    'Multiple lines of code

    If Foo(arg1,arg2) Then

        'Multiple lines of code

    End If

    Exit Sub

  ErrHandler:
    Error handling mechanism here.
End Sub
```